# Question Concerning Responding to Employer of Minor Daughter Paid Under Minimum Wage

Tags: employment, california, teenager

My high school daughter worked for about a year for an employer who owns a tutoring company in our town. Due to friction between my daughter and the employer, my daughter recently quit but she realized that she was being underpaid for much of this year (2023) because the minimum wage here in California is currently $15.50 for 2023 but she was still getting paid $14.00, the California minimum wage for 2022, when she recently quit (in August 2023). Now according to my daughter there is a provision in California law which allows employers to pay only 85% of minimum wage for new workers with no prior experience for their first 160 hours of work. For 2023, that "new worker" wage level would work out to $13.17 per hour, but my daughter said that she exceeded her first 160 hours of work for the employer back in March 2023. So, basically, my daughter was being paid under the proper CA 2023 minimum wage for over the past 4 months.

When my daughter contacted her former employer about this problem, the employer was apologetic and emailed back saying that a financial transaction to her to correct for the underpayment would be sent as soon as my daughter emailed back an enclosed payment settlement form. The settlement form basically says "I hereby agree that the net payment of $XXX represents the full and final settlement of my account with Company XXX", and there are signature lines at the bottom of the form for my daughter's signature as well as my signature as her parent.

I'm currently thinking "Why should I, the parent, need to sign anything here?". The employer underpaid my daughter and she acknowledges that she underpaid my daughter, so it seems that she is responsible for paying my daughter the money she already owes her for the work that my daughter already did, regardless of whether I sign any form or not. Any thoughts on all of this?

Comment: you don't have to , they must meet the law regardless, they're just saying it'll be easy if you do this.

Comment: @TigerGuy - I'm no lawyer, but it seems that it should be easy for my daughter to get the amount of the underpayment for work she already did whether I sign the form or not since the employer has admitted to the underpayment and taking her to small claims court is always an option.

Answer (score 3):

### Read the terms

It’s quite likely that, if you took this to court, the employer would be liable to pay your daughter interest on the underpayment and possibly be fined by the state for failing to follow the law.

The terms probably are offering to pay the back pay with no interest and your daughter agreeing to confidentiality about the breach. Probably - I haven’t read them.

In other words, they’re asking her to sign a contract saying she gets $XXX now, and can’t make any further claims against them. Such releases are commonplace when setting a dispute and there’s probably nothing underhanded going on. Probably - I haven’t read them.

Because minors can void contracts if they are not in their interest, they want you, as her legal guardian, to also sign so that can’t happen. A relatively prudent precaution on their part.

The alternative is to not sign the document and they presumably won’t pay. It will then be up to you whether to sue them which will cost you money, possibly more than you will get if you win.

As to whether there is a dispute: they want your signature, you don’t want to sign - that’s a dispute. Any admissions they have made in their settlement offer are almost surely without prejudice, meaning they are inadmissible in court. If you want to sue, you would have to prove the underpayment without relying on their admissions. As stated above, maybe there is no underpayment.

Only you and your daughter can decide if this is a good deal.

Comment: "Such releases are commonplace when setting a dispute...." - Yes, but I think that a key point here is that there is no dispute here concerning the facts of this case. Both sides agree that my daughter was underpaid. So I don't see the point of signing a settlement dispute form. If I don't sign the form and the employer refused to pay my daughter the money that she is rightfully owed, then I would think that my daughter could take the employer to small claims court and it would be a slam-dunk case to win since she has a text message from her employer admitting that my daughter was underpaid.

Comment: @BarneyCowell it seems that you have come to the conclusion that there's no need to sign the form (and I suppose you're right about that).  If so, why have you posted this question asking whether _you_ need to sign the form?  If the form doesn't need to be signed then of course you don't need to sign it.

Comment: @phoog - "it seems that you have come to the conclusion that there's no need to sign the form (and I suppose you're right about that)."  - For reasons stated above, I certainly do have strong thoughts on what I believe that the law should say in a situation like this. However, since I'm not a lawyer and have no legal training, I came to this website to get clarification on this matter and to gain a broader understanding of all the legal issues involved here, including finding out if there are important legal issues that I may have overlooked.

Comment: To phoog’s point though, your mention of going to court is something that all parties would likely prefer to avoid, therefore if the company is able to secure the agreement of an adult they stand a better chance of avoiding “papa bear” later deciding his minor daughter didn’t get enough.  You have been offered a remedy you agree with, take the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 1):

The form most likely includes a statement somewhere that you won’t take further legal action.  Your underage daughters signature would not be legally binding as she is underage, and so you could get the money and sue.

Your signature on the other hand makes it a legally binding contract on your part and would probably open you up to a breach of contract suit if your daughter was to sue in her own right (either before or after majority).